# Viewport Render Animation playback not loading in Blender

Tags: rendering, animation, image

Whenever I run a viewport render animation by clicking View->Viewport Render Animation in Blender 2.93.5, the files are written to disk in the '/tmp/' folder, but they are not loaded into blender for playback.

I don't really want to have to write out a .mov every time and load it in quicktime. I see video tutorials where the resulting render automatically pops up.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Render > View Animation* and the animation will pop-up:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any reason why the animation is 1/4 the size of the window?

Comment: maybe check the Output panel > Dimensions > % ?

Comment: 1920x1080 at 100%. Looks fine when I open up an image. Something specific to the Blender animation player.

Comment: Looks like it's a known bug on macos: https://developer.blender.org/D9837